# Kue connect Redis at AWS EC2 fail, show `Caught exception: AbortError`

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, redis, kue

I use docker to run redis on AWS EC2 and I use kue to connect to it at my node server.
But it shows error like below. 
How could I fix this? I use redis-cli to ping to IP and GUI tool to connect redis are woring fine.

```
Caught exception:  AbortError
11:05:00 0|server   |     at RedisClient.flush_and_error (/Users/Project/node_modules/kue/node_modules/redis/index.js:357:23)
11:05:00 0|server   |     at RedisClient.connection_gone (/Users/Project/node_modules/kue/node_modules/redis/index.js:659:14)
11:05:00 0|server   |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Project/node_modules/kue/node_modules/redis/index.js:293:14)
11:05:00 0|server   |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
11:05:00 0|server   |     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
11:05:00 0|server   |     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
11:05:00 0|server   |     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
11:05:00 0|server   |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
11:05:00 0|server   |     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
11:05:00 0|server   |   code: 'UNCERTAIN_STATE',
11:05:00 0|server   |   command: 'BLPOP',
11:05:00 0|server   |   args: [ 'q:processSendEMail:jobs', 0 ] }
```